# Issue related to the parameter of report in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho

I have a chart that contains 4 parameters and every parameter is related to the following one, i success i having the result of the chart by selecting the whole parameters one after the other,

The probleme is that i want to have another option by having the result of the chart by selecting also just one parameter or having the result without selecting any parameter

Can you please help me as soon as possible

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is one checkbox available while creating a parameter "Mandatory".Just remove the Right click from the checkboxes while creating all four parameters.Now you can check your result while selecting any parameter you want.